# Как лучше работать с интерфейсами в Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, интерфейс

Допустим у меня есть интерфейс Joke, у которого есть пару методов: получение шутки и сохранение в лучшие. Этот интерфейс реализуют два класса, и инжектятся в другой сервис. Правильно ли с точки зрения спринга, заинжектить их в List, делать проверку и в зависимости от условия использовать тот или иной? Более общий вопрос, как правильно использовать интерфейсы в идеалогии спринга?

Comment: Да нету никакой идеологии Spring-а. Откуда Вы это берёте? Как правильно Вам тут никто не расскажет, делайте как умеете. Если поставленную задачу Ваш код решает, значит всё правильно. По-делу: да, можно инжектить бины листом, если они один интерфейс реализуют. Но повтрою, это нельзя оценивать как "правильно/не правильно". Spring позволяет Вам так сделать. Точка.

Comment: @zolt не согласен, есть определенные best practice, которые даже сами Pivotal рекомендуют использовать, например, не инжектить через Autowired, если у нас есть зависимость в одном из bean-методов, то лучше инжектить в параметры этого метода, если в нескольких bean-методах, то через Autowired, и таких примеров полно.

Comment: @zolt по факту, можно вообще инжектить контекст в каждый компонент и доставать бины так, тоже будет работать, но это не значит, что это хорошо.

Comment: согласен, но best practice всё же не идеология. Всё равно надо плясать от поставленной задачи. Плюс интерфейсов в том, что можно например подменять реализацию в тестах, полностью или частично. Если есть такая задача, делаем интерфес - работаем. Если есть много одиннаковых объектов - тоже есть плюс. Как понимать какую реализацию использовать? Вариантов масса. Например, дженерики. Например, имена бинов. Например, метод supports в самом интерфейсе, т.е. объект может сказать, поддерживает ли он нужную нам реализацию. Но опять же, это не идеология и тем более не идеология Spring-a.

Comment: @zolt ну да, наверное, с идеалогией я погоричился.

Comment: @zolt P.S. реализацию в тестах тоже можно подменять, мокито с этим хорошо справляется.